# Redirect permanent (SSL)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I do this:

`Redirect permanent /ANY_TWO_CHARACTERS/secure/ANY_PATH https://example.com/THE_ANY_TWO_CHARACTERS/secure/ANY_PATH`

I tried:

`Redirect permanent /(..)/secure(.*) https://example.com/secure$1`

It's not working. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use regular expressions with `Redirect` directive, you need to use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/../secure/(.*)$ https://example.com/secure/$1
```

Your regex has a `(..)` as the first grouping, so `$1` would have been those "ANY_TWO_CHARACTERS" instead of the "ANY_PATH".

---

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?../clients/ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That is not working correctly: http:// domain.com/en/clients/new/ => https:// domain.com/en/new/ while it should redirect to https:// domain.com/en/clients/new/

Comment: @AdamSilver For me, [it's working exactly as you asked](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pQae8.png): **"`/ANY_TWO_CHARACTERS/secure/ANY_PATH https://example.com/secure/ANY_PATH`"**

Comment: "clients" is chopped, I certainly do not want that. What I am trying to achieve is: redirecting any user to https but the real issue is I have many languages just after the domain name. I don't want to have the rule for every language, that's why I have .. to match an language code.

Comment: @AdamSilver Your question doesn't say anything about "clients", but I'm assuming it's where "secure" is in your question. If you look at the screenshot in my last comment, the redirect doesn't remove the "secure", it only removes the 2 characters, the "`ANY_TWO_CHARACTERS`" that's in your question.

Comment: secure is clients, sorry for the confusion but still. Your code removes clients after redirecting. By ANY_TWO_CHARACTERS I don't mean to remove them, I just want to make the redirection to the current language specified in path which is happening now but clients is missing.

Comment: @AdamSilver But in your question, you have `ANY_TWO_CHARACTERS` removed from your redirect target: `https://example.com/secure/ANY_PATH`, so... I guess I have no idea what you want

Comment: @AdamSilver If you're just redirecting a specific set of URL's from http to https, then you need to use mod_rewrite. See the edited part of answer.